# Split regex with multi char delimiters

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm battling to find the correct way to split a string using delimiters with multiple characters in Java (e.g. '. [1a]' or '.(2b)')

Here's a test case:

```
String str1 = "This is test 1  .  This is test 2  [2 b]. This is test 3 (3). This is test 4.[4a] This is a test 5 . This is test 6 . (6,six)";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s{0,}\\[.*\\]\\s{0,}|\\.\\s{0,}\\(.*\\)\\s{0,}|\\.\\s{0}");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(regex.split(text)));
```

The output that I'm aiming for is the following (spaces in the beginning or end of each sub-string are fine, the important thing is to keep the delimiter):

> [This is test 1  . , This is test 2  [2 b]. , This is test 3 (3). ,
>   This is test 4.[4a] , This is a test 5 . , This is test 6 . (6,six)]

However, this is the output I'm getting:

> [This is test 1  ,  This is test 2  [2 b], This is test 3 (3), This is
>   test 4, This is a test 5 , This is test 6 ]

Also tried dropping the "\\s", a different notation for spaces like `Pattern.compile("\\s+\\[.?\\]\\s+\\.|\\s+\\(.?\\)\\s+\\.|\\.\\s+")` and experimented with lookaheads like `Pattern.compile("(?<=[.[*]\\s+])|(?=[.(*)]\\s+)|\\.")` but neither helped :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit tricky. Focus on the common characteristics that the wanted group ends when the next one begins - there is a letter `\w` so use that to detect a new group.

Use this advantage to replace it with self and the `\n` before it, thus `\n$1` and each group will appear on a new line which is fairly easy to extract. The wanted Regex (see [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6Szfxy/1)) is :

```
 (?<!\w )(\w)(?=\w{2,})
```

- Mind the one  (space) at the first character of the Regex!

This would produce an output as:

```
This is test 1  . 
This is test 2  [2 b].
This is test 3 (3).
This is test 4.[4a]
This is a test 5 .
This is test 6 . (6,six)
```

In Java, the code would be using the methods `replaceAll` and `split` (thanks [@jmng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496890/jmng) for the improvement):

```
String str1 = "This is test 1  .  This is test 2  [2 b]. This is test 3 (3). This is test 4.[4a] This is a test 5 . This is test 6 . (6,six)";

Pattern reg1 = Pattern.compile(" (?<!\\w )(\\w)(?=\\w{2,})");              // Preparation
Pattern regNewline = Pattern.compile("\n");                                // Split
String[] array = regNewline.split(reg1.matcher(str1).replaceAll("\n$1"));  // Apply


Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);                         // Test it
```

Comment: This works, and actually handles smooth variations like multiple partial delimiters (e.g. [][]) or subtle changes like adding or removing spaces. Though I must confess it'll take me a while to understand it! :P

Comment: To take advantage of compiled Patterns: `Pattern reg1 = Pattern.compile(" (?<!\\w )(\\w)(?=\\w{2,})"); Pattern regNewline = Pattern.compile("\n"); String str1 ="text to regex [whatever]";  regNewline.split(reg1.matcher(str1).replaceAll("\n$1"));`

Comment: You teach me as well, I have never used `Pattern::split` before. I'll include it in the answer with your permission.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility if spaces in the beginning or end of each sub-string are acceptable and using split could be to use an alternation with a  positive lookbehind checking for your different requirements.

In Java you have to determine the minimum and maximum possible lengths of the lookbehind so you might for example take 10 for your example data.

`(?<=\[[^]]{1,10}]\.|\.\[[^]]{1,10}]|\([^)]{1,10}\)\.| \. (?!\([^)]+\)))`

In Java:

`(?<=\\[[^]]{1,10}]\\.|\\.\\[[^]]{1,10}]|\\([^)]{1,10}\\)\\.| \\. (?!\\([^)]+\\)))`

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to check what is on the left is

  - `\[[^]]{1,10}]\.` Use a negated character class to match between square brackets and a quantifier that repeats not a closing bracket 1 - 10 times followed by a dot
  - `|` Or
  - `\.\[[^]]{1,10}]` Match a dot and use a negated character class to match between square brackets and a quantifier that repeats not a closing bracket 1 - 10 times
  - `|` Or
  - `\([^)]{1,10}\)\.` Use a negated character class to match between parenthesis and a quantifier that repeats not a closing parenthesis 1 - 10 times
  - `|` Or
  - `\. (?!\([^)]+\))` A space, dot and a space if what follows is not anything between parenthesis
- `)` Close positive lookbehind

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/pHCc0j)

Comment: Thanks, I checked your demo but I'm not sure the output matches. The last element of the array should be "This is test 6 . (6,six)" and it seems that there are two elements that aren't being split ("This is test 4.[4a] This is a test 5 ."); or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: @jmng You are right, I have updated my answer and added to split on square brackets where a dot is before or after it. Also only split on space dot space when not followed by parenthesis.

Comment: The new version does indeed work for the given example, but it seems that Nikolas' suggestion is a bit more robust, e.g. it handles smooth variations like multiple partial delimiters (e.g. [][]) or subtle changes like adding or removing spaces.